# Can one limit how far down the sliderbody will go on a (vert) scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Here's is a diagram where it clearly shows what I mean exactly with the sliderbody, the "button" you can select and drag down a vertical scrollbar.
http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/images/scroll.gif

My question is simple. Given a hypothetical height of 100px, can I somehow block users from reaching the last 20% when scrolling downwards? ie, "block" it at 80px without changing the height of the element? I'm hoping for a CSS solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Given a `div` with hypothetical height of 100px, you could use absolute or relative positioning:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
}
```

Comment: that might work but I can't see it, probably because I have a "top" style definition already for that element to center it vertically (using position, top and margin-top properties). My issue is, when I add an image into said div element, where the content is higher than the containing div, it seems to want to add a small 5px margin at the bottom of if, even though I've defined margins and padding to 0, meaning that the scroll bar always goes down those extra few pixels instead of stopping at the lower edge of the image.